# Переход по ссылке через window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перехватываю в документе событие `click` по любой ссылке для выполнения определенных действий перед переходом на следующую страницу, и потом перенаправляю пользователя. Для созранения возможности открытия ссылки в новой вкладке пишу такой код:

```
if (this.target == '_blanc') window.open(link, '_blanc');
else document.location = link;
```

Проблема в том, что новая вкладка открывается только один раз. Допустим, открыли ссылку в новой вкладке, а сами перешли работать в предыдущую, и там опять открыли ссылку в новой вкладке - вместо того, чтобы открыть третью вкладку, браузер поменяет страницу во второй. Если же ссылку с `target = "_blanc"` открыть во второй вкладке (открытой из первой), то вместо создания новой вкладки браузер просто перейдет по этой ссылке в ней же.

Comment: Почему-то казалось, что правильней писать `window.open(url , '_blank');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может вместо `_blanc` нужно `_blank`?

Второй параметр в [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) ­— название окна. Видимо, потому он в этом же окошке и грузит, что вы ему такое же название (`_blanc`) передаёте.

Comment: Если второй параметр - это название окна, то какое значение туда записывать? Случайную строку?

Comment: Туда нужно написать ключевую строку `_blank` — вы всё делали правильно, просто допустили ошибку в этом слове.

Comment: _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default